# UIUserNotificationSettings can't work

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

```
var categories: NSSet = NSSet(object: firstCategory)
let types: UIUserNotificationType = UIUserNotificationType.Badge | UIUserNotificationType.Alert
```

didn't work and says Binary operator '|' cannot be applied to two 'UIUserNotificationType' operands

```
var categories: NSSet = NSSet(object: firstCategory)
var mySettings = UIUserNotificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: [.Alert, .Badge], categories: categories)
```

also didn't work and says Cannot assign to immutable expression of type 'UIUserNotificationSettings.Type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
var categories = Set(arrayLiteral: firstCategory)
var mySettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: [.Alert, .Badge], categories: categories)
```

You had too many `=` in your second line. Also, you need to use a `Set` instead of an `NSSet`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set like this :

```
    var categories: Set = Set(object: firstCategory)
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerUserNotificationSettings(UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: UIUserNotificationType.Alert, UIUserNotificationType.Badge categories: categories))
```